# Exclude a URL from rewrite in .htaccess with "last" flag

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, oscommerce

WordPress has been installed as a blog into osCommerce. I'm trying to get the WordPress RSS feed to work. All WP core files exist, but I get all kinds of errors accessing the feed at mydomain.com/wordpress/feed/, like 404s, "the feed can't be updated because the source file is no longer available," or even raw php code in the browser from the osCommerce feed file.

I think the problem is the rewrite rules for osCommerce, and I'm thinking if I can exclude the WP feed URL from rewrite, it will fix the feed or help find the real issue.

Looking around SO, I found a solution to use the "last" flag on a URL to prevent it from being rewritten. Problem is, the existing .htaccess already has a rule with a "last" flag on it.

Is there a way to not rewrite the WP feed URL? Can another "last" rule be added? I'd like to have some definite things to try before messing with .htaccess to avoid disrupting the site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?cPath=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^(.*)-t-([0-9_]+).html$ articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-au-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php?authors_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0-9]+).html$ article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
# Information pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^(.*)-links-([0-9_]+).html$ links.php?lPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^(.*)-n-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nc-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_index.php?newsPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nri-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nra-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_article.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess? If there’s more, show us.

Comment: It's all there now; I had thought the last flag line was the most important....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use two .htaccess files: one in your wordpress directory which catches all requests which should be handled by WordPress and one in your root directory for the rest.

I’m not so sure about the `%{QUERY_STRING}` in your rewrite rules … test it thoroughly. Also, I don’t have any experience with Magento. The last time I tested it, it was way too slow. :)

As a start, here are the two .htaccess files:

### /wordpress/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

# WordPress allows URLs like /2010/0/ or /00/ == doubled content
RewriteRule (^0+|(.*)/0+)/$ /$2 [L,R=301]

# WordPress: paged content creates a /page/
RewriteRule (^p|(.*)/p)age/(1/)?$ /$2 [L,R=301]

# Images, Stylesheets etc.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.\w{2,4}$
# Existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

### root /.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-t-([0-9_]+).html$ articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-au-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php?authors_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0-9]+).html$ article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
# Information pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-links-([0-9_]+).html$ links.php?lPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-n-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nc-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_index.php?newsPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nri-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_info.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nra-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_article.php?newsdesk_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?cPath=$1 [L]
```

Your web hoster has a very informative [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), which may help if you still have any problems.

Comment: Really appreciate the extensive answer. I'll have more time tomorrow to dive into this. I forgot about the fact that I could put an .htaccess in the wordpress folder and it would supercede the root .htaccess file, and that should make workable what I need to do.

Comment: Just to let you know I gave up on trying to get this to work and passed the issue on to someone else. :) I don't know for sure if your rewrite rules work, but I checked off on the answer for your effort.